# Laravel mix image handling

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, laravel-mix

I have recently switched to laravel-mix from Vue-CLI.
All my images in html stopped working. They were used like this:

```
<img src="@assets/images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
```

(`@assets` is a alias for the resources/assets folder)

With this method, when I look at the html in the browser, I see that it got compiled to `[object Module]`. So I was able to fix it this way:
`<img :src="require('@assets/img/sidebar/logo.png').default" alt="Logo">`

But I can't imagine this being the best solution, it seems very hacky and I dont want to add this `require().default` thing everytime I use an image.

I've tried adding this to the `mix.webpackConfig`:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        esModule: false,
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    ]
}
```

But that doens't do anything, but I don't even know if it works at all to be honest.

Is there a better way to use images with laravel-mix or is `require().default` really the way to go?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately im still forced to using this approach: `<img :src="require('@assets/img/sidebar/logo.png').default" alt="Logo">`

Comment: Yes, the vue-loader removed the `esModule: false` option so now it is the default module. So I am also using the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel-mix [offers](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/aliases) the ability to configure aliases

```
const path = require('path');

mix.alias({
    '@assets': path.join(__dirname, 'resources/assets')
});
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and it didn't work, same outcome, I did have something similar myself setup too:

```mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@assets': path.join(__dirname, 'resources/assets/')
        }
    },```